# Why not signing in causes error "Google Play in-app billing API version is less than 3"

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase, play-billing-library

When Google Play has not been signed in, running [BillingClient.startConnection()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#startconnection) results in BillingResult returned by [onBillingSetupFinished()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClientStateListener.html#onBillingSetupFinished(com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult)) showing billingResult.getDebugMessage():

> Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3

This error is gone as soon as Google Play is signed in.

Is there a way to get an accurate error for this situation?

Comment: I simply if the user tries to buy an item and `onBillingSetupFinished()`  was `billingResult != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`  then I show a message saying that the operation has been canceled and I ask if he has Play Store installed and has logged into it

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that you are using a Google Play Developer API that is lower than v3.

The Google Play Developer API will only support the v3 endpoint after 1 December, 2019. Here is the blog post:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

For more context, the Google Play Billing Library (currently 2.1.0) is the client API used in your Android app.
The Google Play Developer API (currently v3) is the server API used for managing purchases and managing your app on Google Play.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  How come the error is gone if the user signs in with exactly the same version of the app?   I am using  implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'